# Finding the catenary curve through three given points

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods

I have been searching for this, but all I found where solutions, in which the arch length is given, or the sack at the lowest point. I tried also Wolfram Alpha, but it doesn't come up with anything useful.

**This is the problem:** Find the equation for the catenary that goes through three points. It can be assumed that $x_1 < x_3 < x_2$ and $y_1 <= y_2$.

[image]

Here is what I got so far. We can shift the curve so that $P_1$ has coordinates $(0, 0)$. This gives the equations:

$$
0 = a \cosh\left(\frac{-x_0}{a}\right) + y_0 \\
y_2 = a \cosh\left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right) + y_0 \\
y_3 = a \cosh\left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right) + y_0
$$

Its easy to substitute $y_0$:

$$
\frac{y_2}{a} - \cosh\left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right) + \cosh\left(\frac{x_0}{a}\right) = 0\\
\frac{y_3}{a} - \cosh\left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right) + \cosh\left(\frac{x_0}{a}\right) = 0
$$

But then I am stuck. I know at some point I need to use some numerical method. Can this be simplified further?

From here I thought I could use some multi-dimensional root solver or formulate it as a minimization problem.

$$\min_{a, \,x_0}{ \left(\frac{y_2}{a} - \cosh\frac{x_2-x_0}{a} + \cosh\frac{x_0}{a}\right)^2 + 
\left(\frac{y_3}{a} - \cosh\frac{x_3-x_0}{a} + \cosh\frac{x_0}{a}\right)^2 }$$

This leaves the question of good start values and if this space is convex, which I honestly doubt.

Comment: I think you'll get good starting points by using one of 2 approximations: either cosh=1+x^2/2 or cosh=e^x/2

Answer (score 2):

Since you can have some errors for the values of the $(x_i,y_i)$ and a single variable $a$, I should let the problem as it is and  consider the norm (to be minimized)
$$\Phi(a)=\Bigg[a \cosh\left(\frac{x_1-x_0}{a}\right) + (y_0-y_1) \Bigg]^2+
\Bigg[ a \cosh\left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right) + (y_0-y_2) \Bigg]^2+$$ $$\Bigg[a \cosh\left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right) + (y_0-y_3)\Bigg]^2$$ which corresponds to something like *data validation* or *data reconciliation*.  This is very similar to what you propose.

We can compute the derivative which, simplified, leads to the problem of finding the zero of the expression
$$\left(a \cosh \left(\frac{x_1-x_0}{a}\right)+(y_0-y_1)\right)
   \left((x_0-x_1) \sinh \left(\frac{x_1-x_0}{a}\right)+a \cosh
   \left(\frac{x_1-x_0}{a}\right)\right)+$$
$$\left(a \cosh \left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right)+(y_0-y_2)\right)
   \left((x_0-x_2) \sinh \left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right)+a \cosh
   \left(\frac{x_2-x_0}{a}\right)\right)+$$
$$\left(a \cosh \left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right)+(y_0-y_3)\right)
   \left((x_0-x_3) \sinh \left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right)+a \cosh
   \left(\frac{x_3-x_0}{a}\right)\right)$$

Any root finding algorithm will be fine.

Comment: Thank you I really like this and it gives me a lot of insights. 

I noticed some problems in my approach above, so there is room for improvement. 

One thing I am curious is you say we have a single variable a, while I assumed we have three (a, x0, y0)?

Comment: @Chris. I am sorry because I misread the problem !